# How to change select dropdown order on asp form load using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

my code:

```
    arrayKeys = dictCatProd.Keys       
    for each k in arrayKeys

        Response.write(vbTab & vbTab & "catprod[""" & k & """] = [];" & vbcrlf)
        Response.write(vbTab & vbTab & "catNames[""" & k & """] = """ & dictCategories(cint(k)) & """;" & vbcrlf)
        prods = Split(dictCatProd(k), "|")

        for each p in prods


            if Trim(p)<>"" then
                Response.write(vbTab & vbTab & "prodNames[""" & Trim(p) & """] = """ & dictProducts(cint(Trim(p))) & """;" & vbcrlf)
                Response.write(vbTab & vbTab & "catprod[""" & k & """].push(" & Trim(p) & ");" & vbcrlf)

            end if
        next

        'append the categories to the category dropdown

 $("#catSel").append("<option value='" + <%=k %> + "'>"+ catNames[<%=k %>] + "</option>");
```

my question is:

when dropdown binding, i want to change order like item at 5th position should come into 2nd position. how can i do this?

Comment: Given that you seem to be using jQuery, you could use the [`.before()` method](http://api.jquery.com/before/). But how do you know which item to move and where it should move to? Or is it *always* the 5th item moving up to become the 2nd item?

Comment: if item value==5 then it comes to 2nd position. can you give code for above   code.

Comment: or move up 5th item to 2nd item.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't tagged "jQuery", but you do seem to be using jQuery in your code so I'd suggest using [jQuery's `.insertBefore()` method](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore). That method can be used to insert new content, but if the target is a single element and the item being inserted already exists in the DOM then that element is *moved*.

So, something like the following should do it, after your existing code. Note that as far as the [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq) is concerned element indices start at zero, so your fifth and second elements have indices `4` and `1`.

```
var options = $("#catSel option")
options.eq(4).insertBefore(options.eq(1))
```

If you couldn't use jQuery you could do something similar to the above but using the standard [DOM `.insertBefore()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

```js
var select = document.getElementById("catSel")
select.insertBefore(select.options[4], select.options[1])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="catSel" multiple size="6">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
  <option value="5">Fifth</option>
  <option value="6">Sixth</option>
</select>
```

Note that the DOM method is called on the *parent* element, but the jQuery method is called on the element being moved.

(I've used a hard-coded select element with the `multiple` attribute just for demo purposes.)